# How do I make js make chips according to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, materialize, roblox

I've been wondering how to make chips according to JSON. Here's my JSON.

```json
{
  "friends": {
    "count": "9",
    "friends": [
      "Xdevil_blueX",
      "SpectakularBaby_YT",
      "kingdondon96",
      "Xxaland366xX",
      "imbadinarsenal_99",
      "EnderMox2",
      "No0dles_s",
      "cracon999",
      "ionwarrior123"
    ]
  }
}
```

So for each friend, I want it to output this Materialize chip.

```html
<div class="chip">
  <img
    src="https://www.roblox.com/headshot-thumbnail/image?userId=1816015877&width=60&height=60&format=png"
    alt="Contact Person"
  />
  ionwarrior123
</div>
```

I would hope the end result would look like this:

[image]

Comment: you have tagged node.js means you must be using some template engine like pug, jade etc? and data must be coming from server? clarify these things in questions

Comment: Show some efforts , some code and try to explain everything in detail.

Comment: Without their [userID](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/UserId) you would not be able to.